# Regarding adldap2 getting users details

Tags: php, laravel-9, adldap

In adldap2 how to get the users information in previous adLDAP we use info() method but in adldap2.

I used findByDn and search() with condition but both of it showed null value for the return attributes. I used find as they said info is same as aliases